# setBackgroundColor does not work in QTreeWidget when I reimplement paint function

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I have reimplemented `paint()` function, but after that when I want to change the color of `topLevelItem` when it expands, `setBackgroundColor` is not working.

How can I fix it?
I used connection; when I toggle breakpoint, the slot executes but `setbackgroundColor` doesn't change color.

my slot:

```
void Form::on_treeWidget_expanded(QTreeWidgetItem *item)
{
    item->setBackgroundColor(0, (QColor::fromCmyk(15, 15, 15, 40, 255)).toRgb());
}
```

my paint function :

```
const QString txt = index.data().toString();
painter->save();
QRect rect = option.rect;
drawDisplay(painter, option, rect, txt);
rect.setX(0);
painter->restore();
```

Comment: I must admit I am not familiar with fromCmyk, but a standard approach would be to exclude that as a cause by replacing it with e.g. the simple QColor(Qt::green).

Comment: Just a guess: In the overridden `paint()`, did you call the parent's `paint()` too?

Comment: yes i didn't call parrent

Comment: You should have. Call it in the first line (`QWidget::paint(...)` if the immediate parent is `QWidget`) and see if your problem goes away.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].